# SQL join two tables where IDs match

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables in my database.

`Movies` table:

```
+----------------------------------------
| ID | title                | timestamp |
+----------------------------------------
| 1  | The host             | time      |
| 2  | Fight Club           | time      |
| 4  | 21                   | time      |
----------------------------------------+
```

`Movie_Links` table:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| ID | link                 | movie_id  |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | some link            | 1         |
| 2  | some link            | 1         |
| 3  | some link            | 1         |
+---------------------------------------+
```

At the moment I am only selecting the rows from the `Movies` table where the `title` is like for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `Movies` 
WHERE `title` LIKE '%The Host%' 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC DESC LIMIT 30
```

But what I want to do is the same query as above but join `Movie_Links` table where `movie_id` equals `Movies` table's `ID` and get all links that have a `Movie_id` equal to `1`.

Comment: Capitalizing Your Whole Post In Title Case Makes It A Real Pain To Read. I've fixed that. Thank you in advance for using normal capitalization in future posts! :)

Answer (score 14):

**SQL join two tables With IDs match**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Movies 
LEFT JOIN Movie_Links 
ON Movies.ID = Movie_Links.movie_id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Test the following query :

```
SELECT ml.id,m.title,m.timestamp, ml.link
FROM movies m ,Movie_Links ml
WHERE m.id=ml.movie_id and title LIKE '%The Host%'
```

BR,

Answer (score 1):

Just join on the matching columns:

```
SELECT * FROM movies m
JOIN MovieLinks ml
ON ml.movie_id = m.id
WHERE m.title LIKE '%The Host%'
```

Comment: Well i try you query but i only have 2 movies named `The Host` But Now it's returning 46 all most same number of links i have for that movie

Comment: This query will return all links for all movies where name is like `%The Host%`, If you want to get links for only for the movie which has an id of 1, then change your where to `WHERE m.ID = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try join (removed order by clause as i dont see those fields in above question):

```
SELECT m.*, ml.link 
FROM movies m join Movie_Links ml
ON   m.id = ml.movie_id 
WHERE m.title LIKE '%The Host%' 
AND   m.id = 1
AND   ml.id = 1
--ORDER BY `featured` DESC,`date_added` DESC,`released` DESC LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this for a join :

```
SELECT * FROM 'movies'
WHERE 'title" LIKE '%The Host%'
AND Movies.id = Links.id
AND Links.id = 1
ORDER BY 'featured' DESC, 'date_added' DESC, 'released' DESC LIMIT 30
```